# Submitting a form for each accordion

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, accordion

I have an accordion with 4 headers/sections, each having a form inside it. I am needing to have each form be submitted to the server and a callback given, as well as the validation before the user can go on to the next step in the process. I have the validation working - i just used the default settings. Now how do I get a callback for each form being submitted? I know that i need to assign each Next button to submit, but I don't know how to do that with this script, since this script was designed for a single submit for one form.

I am also not allowed to use PHP, as it's not something we use here. We use JSP for datacalls, so please refrain from PHP responses. thank you.

My Script for validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// add * to required field labels
$('label.form-field-label-required').append('&nbsp;<strong>*</strong>');

// accordion functions
var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
var current = 0; 

$.validator.addMethod("pageRequired", function(value, element) {
    var $element = $(element)
    function match(index) {
        return current == index && $(element).parents("#accordion").length;
    }
    if (match(0) || match(1) || match(2)) {
        return !this.optional(element);
    }
    return "dependency-mismatch";
}, $.validator.messages.required)


    var v = $("#cmaForm").validate({
    errorClass: "warning",
    onkeyup: false,
    onblur: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("Submitted, thanks!");
    }
});


// back buttons do not need to run validation
$(".prevbutton").click(function(){
    accordion.accordion("activate", 0);
    current = 0;
}); 
$(".prevbutton").click(function(){
    accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
    current = 1;
}); 
// these buttons all run the validation, overridden by specific targets above
$(".open2").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 2);
    current = 2;
  }
});
$(".open1").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
    current = 1;
  }
});
$(".open0").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 0);
    current = 0;
  }
});
});
```

My script for form submit: (i don't know what's going on with the formatting of the form submit script, but it shouldn't look like that)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#output2',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
    clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit     

}; 

$('#cmaForm').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData);

```
alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
return true;
```

}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {

```
alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
    '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to first validate then submit. See the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

e.g

```
$('#cmaForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var options = { 
            target: '#output2',  
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,  
            success: showResponse,  
            clearForm: true           
        };

        // Do the submit
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am validating before submitting. My problem is how do I apply that to each Next button without it affecting the Back button. I realize that I have two different submit scripts, I gave both examples to show what I am currently working with, but it would seem that I only need one script for both validation and submission, I just don't know which - but I am guessing it's the first script, since the second script deals with only the submission and not any validation. Forgive me for not being clearer about that. I am so frustrated after working on this for a week.

Comment: I came up with something that seems a bit of a hack, though I'm not sure how to post the code up here without editing my original post. But anyway, now that I get the submit for each accordion section, the validation doesn't work after the first section. ugh

Comment: @nutless_neo It's perfectly acceptable to write your own answer if you find one so just just do that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was just afraid that was going to close the issue - which is not what I want to do - but anyhow, here is the "solution" I came up with, but as I said, now the validation for the second and third sections isn't working. I'm sure it's something simple to do with the button call, but I'm no expert by any means. Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// add * to required field labels
$('label.form-field-label-required').append('&nbsp;<strong>*</strong>');

// accordion functions
var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
var current = 0; 

$.validator.addMethod("pageRequired", function(value, element) {
    var $element = $(element)
    function match(index) {
        return current == index && $(element).parents("#accordion").length;
    }
    if (match(0) || match(1) || match(2)) {
        return !this.optional(element);
    }
    return "dependency-mismatch";
}, $.validator.messages.required)

var v = $("#cmaForm, #cmaForm1, #cmaForm2").validate({
    errorClass: "warning",
    onkeyup: false,
    onblur: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
        var options = { 
        clearForm: true };          
        alert("Submitted, thanks!");
    }
```

});

```
$(" .prevbutton").click(function(){
    accordion.accordion("activate", 0);
    current = 0;
}); 
$(" .prevbutton").click(function(){
    accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
    current = 1;
}); 
// these buttons all run the validation, overridden by specific targets above
$(".open2").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 2);
    current = 2;
  }
});
$(".open1").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
    current = 1;
  }
});
$(".open0").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    accordion.accordion("activate", 0);
    current = 0;
  }
});
```

});